# sumar visitas a las cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

Estoy aprendiendo a usar las cookies y necesito contar el numero de visitas realizadas a una página.He intentado crear este código en el que en teoria se suma una visita cuando alguien entra en la página y digo en teoria porque he imaginado que pódria funcionar así, ademas de si alguien me puede confirmar si esto es así, me gustaría saber como las puedo visualizar en mi pantalla, ya que las llamo en un html al pulsar un boton y lo unico que obtengo es un mensaje vacio.

```js
document.cookie = 'visitas=' + 1;
function alertCookie() {
  alert(document.cookie); // visualizar: visitas +1
}
```

edit: Me piden que haga una cuenta de mis propias visitas a una página y que al llegar a 10 las elimine o que expiren en un mes si no superan las 10 visitas propias hechas por mi a esa página, es para clase no uso servidores ni nada asi

Comment: Las _cookies_ se guardan en el navegador del visitante, por lo que solo va a contar las vistas desde la misma computadora y mismo navegador... bueno, suponiendo que el usuario tiene _cookies_ activadas. Para saber cómo guardar y leer visita [esta página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: si estoy tratando de hacer que guarde las visitas que hago yo misma a mi propia pagina, ya he visitado ese documento, pero no logro que funcione

Comment: primero leer la cookie, luego sumarle, luego guardarla

Comment: `document.cookie` trae todas las cookies en un string, hay que encontrar ( si existe ) la que usas para contar las visitas (  indexOf suele ser útil ahí ) con el valor encontrado  sumar a la cantidad y guardar o borrar la cookie según corresponda. el tiempo de un mes lo seteas con `max-age` o `expires` ( al crear la cookie si no existía )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, hay que definir la lógica de tu *script*:

1. Obtener la *cookie* y asignar el valor a `visitas`
2. Verificar que el valor es numérico o asignar cero
3. Sumar 1
4. Comparar el valor para determinar qué hacer
5. Mostrar el valor
6. Guardar *cookie*

Comenzamos con lo básico:

```
// Crear variable y asignar valor desde cookie
let visitas = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)visitas\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
// Asegurar que tiene un valor entero o asignar cero si algo falla
visitas = parseInt(visitas) || 0;
// Incrementar
visitas ++;
// Comparar
if(visitas >= 10) {
    // Mostrar mensaje
    alert('Ya hiciste 10 visitas');
    // No es necesario borrar la cookie, solo reiniciar cuenta
    visitas = 0;
} else {
    // Mostrar mensaje con cantidad de visitas
    alert('Hasta ahora llevas ' + visitas + ' visitas');
}
// Guardar cookie que expire en 30 días
document.cookie = 'visitas=' + visitas + '; max-age=2592000';
```

Algunas referencias necesarias:

- [Cómo definir una variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)
- [Cómo leer una *cookie*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie#Ejemplo_2_Obtener_una_cookie_de_ejemplo_llamada_test2)
- [Convertir una cadena en entero](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt)
- [Incrementar valor en 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)
- [Cómo guardar una cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.cookie#Ejemplo)

Estoy usando alertas para mostrar los mensajes, porque no especificaste cómo quieres que aparezcan en tu página.

**Nota:** Gracias a la sugerencia de @AloMalbarez, agregué la opción para que la *cookie* expire en 30 días usando max-age (en segundos) 60 * 60 * 24 * 30.

Comment: mmm una duda porque podría ser que no se me muestran mis cookies en el navegador? muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!!! es un mareo saber hacer esto si no consigues ver el resultado :(

Comment: faltaría el expires para que no se borre al cerrar la pestaña o ventana

Comment: @azucarilla, creo que los navegadores no van a guardar _cookies_ si estás abriendo el documento HTML directamente desde una carpeta (en la barra de direcciones aparece algo como `file:///c:\ruta\archivo.html`), por lo que deberías instalar un servidor local como [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) y cargar desde `http://localhost/archivo.html` para que funcione.

Comment: vale muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    function crearCookie() {

        if (!document.cookie) {
            document.cookie = "Numero de visita = " + 1 + "";
            document.write("<h1>" + document.cookie + "</h1>");
        } else {
            document.cookie.trim();
            let valor = document.cookie.split("=");
            valor[1]++;
            document.cookie = "Numero de visita = " + valor[1] + "";
            document.write("<h1>" + document.cookie + "</h1>");
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Pulsa en [edit] y describe su funcionamiento. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.